# Unable to mount device on Linux (XFS)

Tags: linux, boot, mount, centos-5, xfs

I am unable to mount a device on my server due to error when mounting, the device is type XFS. The mount command returns message: "mount: structure needs cleaning"

I've tried using xfs_check and it just returns a message saying that there are entries in the log that need relaying and that you need to run xfs_repair -L where "-L" option deletes the log file but might/will result in data loss/corruption.

Does anyone know if you can access/mount the drive without repairing, or anyway to minimise data loss?

Answer (score 2):

no, you have to repair it first before it will allow it for you to mount.

however, it is a good idea to save your partition or device with dd or ddrescure to an image file, before you do the repair, if you are concerned about data loss.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if you can run xfs_repair without any flags on the device would that cause any issues or is it best to go straight to "-L" option. I did try the "-n" flag and it output a lot of messages that I'm not sure what they mean.

Comment: -L removes the logs even if they are dirty, i.e., unwritten data, so you are more likely to lose files. If the dry run shows a lot of errors, it is better to run it without the -L flag, and use the latter only if the repair fails.

Comment: Just to update it wouldnt run without flags so used -L but all seems ok. I guess there is no way to tell what files are missing. I did find files in lost+found but nothing important.